# How to open and hide ng-bootstrap datepicker on custom actions?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Currently I am using:

- ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.24
- angular/core 4.0.0
- bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6

I wanted to ask if someone knows how to autoclose the datepicker
when the focus is lost or another datepicker is opened.

Also i wanted to now if it is possible to close the datepicker in the component code with typescript.

It would be nice if someone could provide a working plunker or a code snippet.

My actual implementation:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="rect-border full-width"
           placeholder="YYMMDD"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
           ngbDatepicker
           #datePickerInput="ngbDatepicker"
           (keydown.arrowup)="incrementDate()"
           (keydown.arrowdown)="decrementDate()"
           (ngModelChange)="validate('modelChanged')"
           (blur)="validate(null)"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [ngClass]="{'input-required': required, 'normal-color': valid, 'picker-disabled': disabled}">

    <div class="input-group-addon rect-border"
         (click)="disabled ? true : datePickerInput.toggle()"
         [ngClass]="{'picker-button-disabled': disabled}">
        <img src="assets/img/calendar-icon.svg" class="datpickerToggle"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Plunker: [ng-bootstrap team demo](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/popup/plnkr.html)

I have searched a long time and I am also pretty new to angular and these things.

Thank you for your help!

Update:

Possible solution:

There were a lot of good solutions provided.
I also found out by myself that I could use the class NgbInputDatepicker
to close the datePicker (I always used NgbDatepicker, so it didn't work).

```
@ViewChild('datePickerInput') datePicker: NgbInputDatepicker;

this.datePicker.close();
```

Comment: have you changed the `autoclose` property of the datepicker ? ie. `$.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;`

Comment: where could I do this ?
I am using only typescript no javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can open and close your datepicker from your html itself

for eg:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="rect-border full-width"
           placeholder="YYMMDD"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
           ngbDatepicker
           #datePickerInput="ngbDatepicker"
           (keydown.arrowup)="incrementDate()"
           (keydown.arrowdown)="decrementDate()"
           (ngModelChange)="validate('modelChanged')"
           (blur)="validate(null)"
           [disabled]="disabled"
           [ngClass]="{'input-required': required, 'normal-color': valid, 'picker-disabled': disabled}">

    <div class="input-group-addon rect-border"
         (click)="disabled ? true : datePickerInput.toggle()"
         [ngClass]="{'picker-button-disabled': disabled}">
        <img src="assets/img/calendar-icon.svg" class="datpickerToggle"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div (click)="datePickerInput.open()"></div>

<span (click)="datePickerInput.close()"></span>
```

and also there are many functions which you can use in your html. some are `close()`, `isOpen()`, `manualDateChange()`, `open()`, `toggle()`, `validate()` etc. You can refer it in this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/G1b6fFrtVZwEz4lsou8n?p=preview

Comment: thats cool and works!
do you know if I can watch a variable in the component and toggle the datepicker in the html ?
like i got required : boolean and then in html required ? picker.open() : picker.close();

Answer (score 3):

In typescript you can simply define a variable `datepickerVisibility` and then in your template use *ngIf to show or hide your datepicker component. Here is a demo code:

Template: `<datepicker *ngIf="datepickerVisibility" [ngModel]="date"> </datepicker>`

Component: `private datepickerVisibility: boolean = false; 
            // Show the datepicker 
            showDatepicker() {
                 this.datepickerVisibility = true;
            }`

Edit:

Therefore you could use jQuery. Add the jQuery js into your index.html and in your typescript component use jQuery as follows:

```
declare let jQuery: any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    styleUrls: ['test.css'],
})
export class TestComponent {
   constructor() {}

    public toggleDatepicker() {
        jQuery("#datepicker01").toggle();
   }
 }
```

And in your template file just add the id datepicker01 to your datepicker div

`<div id="datepicker01" ...>`

Comment: the problem with this solution is that i use the <div> (with the toggle inside) to open the datepicker.
I have only access to the datepicker via the #datePickerInput attribute

Comment: i like this solution but i don't know how to set the id of the datepicker because i am using it with <input> and not the selector <datepicker>

Comment: Simply set <input id="datepicker01" ...> :)

Comment: i managed to add jquery to my project and get it working but when i add the toggle function to the <input> then the input field disappears.
So jquery does not know there is a datepicker

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to this issue, but in a scenario where the datepicker is wrapped in a custom component and has to expose a function a parent component can call to toggle the datepicker. The answers provided are great and will work for most use case, but not mine, as I didn't want to add a jQuery dependency and calling toggle from the HTML isn't an option.

Here's how I solved it.

I added a `ViewChild` reference to the datepicker input in the *.component.ts file

```
  @ViewChild('d', {static: true}) d;
```

that matches the datepicker identifier in the HTML file

```
<input (dateSelect)="dateSelected($event)" class="form-control" (focus)='d.toggle()' placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="d"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

and called the `toggle` function within a method exposed by the component

```
toggle() {
  this.d.toggle();
}
```

That way, another component can call the `toggle()` function exposed by this component to toggle the datepicker like so:

In HTML

```
<app-custom-datepicker #date></app-custom-date-picker>
```

In .ts file

```
@ViewChild('date', {static: true}) date;
.
.
.
this.date.toggle();
```